# Pydev not found in ubuntu Software center

Tags: software-center, python, eclipse

I installed eclipse  and then wanted to install pydev plugin to execute python programs. 
But it gives an error "pydev not found at https://pydev.org/updates" .

How can I overcome this? And is there any other any alternative?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7651072/cant-install-pydev-for-eclipse-indigo

Comment: It looks like their website is down. Try installing again at a later moment, when the server is up and running again.

Comment: just use [http://pydev.org/updates](http://pydev.org/updates) or [http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates](http://update-production-pydev.s3.amazonaws.com/pydev/updates)

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to install it *through* Eclipse. The PyDev page has the [instructions on how to do this](http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html).

If you are not using Aptana, scroll down to **Installing with the update site** and start there. You'll start by going through **Help > Install New Software...**

I just did it myself on 12.04 and so far everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Ubuntu 16.04 and later, open the terminal and type:

```
sudo apt install eclipse-pydev eclipse-mylyn-context-pydev
```

Optionally you can also install GNU Debugger along with PyDev.

```
 sudo apt install gdb
```